# Why is preg_match_all() returning empty matches array?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Regex pattern: `/{if\s+(isRegion|isCountry)([a-z]+?)}/i`

Expected matches:

```
{if isRegionAsia}

{if isRegionEurope}

{if isCountryChina}
```

Working example here: http://regex101.com/r/gL4qN9/2

Why, then, in PHP, does preg_match_all() return an array with 3 empty results instead of the matches? What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: remove `g` modifier and show your input string - I have no problems with this regexp

Comment: Can you show the PHP code relating to `preg_match` and the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'/{if\s+(isRegion|isCountry)([a-z]+?)}/i'` works just fine for me. See it in action [here](https://eval.in/201250).

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it was working all along.

```
::slowly backs away::
```